# Need help with a Python scraper

Tags: python, image, thumbnails, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to use urllib with python to make a scraper, I can download the images, but they are a thumbnail, 250x250 or less.(I am trying of 4chan, Because I like some of the picture threads)
How can I get the full image?
here is my code

```
    import urllib2, urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urlparse

i = 0

ext = "'src' : re.compile(r'(jpe?g)|(png)|$'"

url = raw_input("Enter URL here:")
ender = raw_input("Enter File Type Here(For Images enter 'img'):")
if ender == "img":
    ender = 'img', {'src' : re.compile(r'(.jpe?g)|(.png)|(.gif)$')}

else:
    if "." in ender:
        end = ender
    else:
        end = ".%s" % ender


raw = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw)

parse = list(urlparse.urlparse(url))

for ender in soup.findAll(ender):
    links = "%(src)s"% ender
    print links
    str(links)
    if ".jpg" in links:
        end = ".jpg"
    if ".jpeg" in links:
        end = ".jpeg"
    if ".gif" in links:
        end = ".gif"
    if ".png" in links:
        end = ".png"
    i += 1
    urllib.urlretrieve(links, "%s%s" % (i, end))
```

Comment: on 4chan, the images are like hyperlinks, just extract the "href" part and download that.

Comment: But what if I want to use them on another website?

Comment: Write a script to parse for the full path to them on 4chan. I can't write you an example as I'm at work and I don't think people will appreciate me doing stuff on 4chan :P

Answer (score 2):

Because you can click to see a larger link, the URL in the `<a href="url">` that is around the image tag points to the full image.

So just read the value of the `href` property, and download that instead of the `src` property of the image.